# How do I count the number of words in a String in Swift?

Tags: swift

Say I have a String, how do I determine the number of words in it? I'm trying to create an extension like:

```
extension String {
    var numberOfWords: Int {
        // Insert string-counting code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

If you search "word count string swift" you'll find dozens of StackOverflow answers and gists that tell you to split the string using `str.components(separatedBy: " ").count`.

**DON'T USE `components(separatedBy:)`!!!**

Many non-European languages (particularly East Asian languages) don't use spaces to split words. This will also incorrectly count hyphenated words as separate, and lone punctuation as a word.

The most correct AND most performant way to solve this problem is to use either `enumerateSubstrings(in:options:)` or `CFStringTokenizer`.

```
// enumerateSubstrings
extension String {
    var numberOfWords: Int {
        var count = 0
        let range = startIndex..<endIndex
        enumerateSubstrings(in: range, options: [.byWords, .substringNotRequired, .localized], { _, _, _, _ -> () in
            count += 1
        })
        return count
    }
}
```

OR:

```
// CFStringTokenizer
extension String {
    var numberOfWords: Int {
        let inputRange = CFRangeMake(0, utf16.count)
        let flag = UInt(kCFStringTokenizerUnitWord)
        let locale = CFLocaleCopyCurrent()
        let tokenizer = CFStringTokenizerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, self as CFString, inputRange, flag, locale)
        var tokenType = CFStringTokenizerAdvanceToNextToken(tokenizer)
        var count = 0
        
        while tokenType != [] {
            count += 1
            tokenType = CFStringTokenizerAdvanceToNextToken(tokenizer)
        }
        return count
    }
}
```

Both are very performant, but `enumerateSubtrings(in:options:...)` is about twice as fast.

Shocked that nobody is pointing this out elsewhere, so I hope people searching for a solution find this.

Comment: In your first example (the one with // enumerateStrings) the line "let range = Range(startIndex..<endIndex)" gives a compile error in Xcode (certainly in Xcode 10.2.1, Swift 5).  The line should instead be "let range = startIndex..<endIndex".

Answer (score -1):

**Count of words in a string**

Create an extension of `String`

```
extension String{
    var wordCount:Int{
        let chararacter = CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines.union(.punctuationCharacters)
        let comps = components(separatedBy: chararacter)
        let words = comps.filter { !$0.isEmpty }
        return words.count
    }
}
```

**How to use**

```
"This is a test string".wordCount // Result: 5
```

Comment: As mentioned in the most upvoted answer, doing this is both incredibly fragile (breaks on most non-latin locales) and slow. Use the proper word separation methods.